# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') with Facebooklogin

Tags: reactjs, facebook-login, web-development-server

I am getting these errors:

ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
at FacebookLogin (https://www.localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1521:30)
at renderWithHooks (https://www.localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:121298:22)

ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
at FacebookLogin (https://www.localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1521:30)
at renderWithHooks (https://www.localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:121298:22)

ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
at FacebookLogin (https://www.localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1521:30)
at renderWithHooks (https://www.localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:121298:22)

from this facebook login code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { LoginSocialFacebook } from "reactjs-social-login";
import { FacebookLoginButton } from "react-social-login-buttons";

function FacebookLogin() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onResolve = (response) => {
      setProfile(response.data);
    };
    const onReject = (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    };
    // Perform any setup or data fetching tasks here...
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!profile ? (
        <LoginSocialFacebook
          appId=process.env.APP_ID
          onResolve={(response) => {
            console.log("Response: ", response);
            if (response && response.data) {
              setProfile(response.data);
            } else {
              console.error("Response or response.data is undefined");
            }
          }}
          onReject={(error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }}
        >
          <FacebookLoginButton />
        </LoginSocialFacebook>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>{profile.name}</h1>
          <img src={profile.picture.data.url} alt="User" />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FacebookLogin;
```

Comment: what does console print on execution of `console.log("Response: ", response)`

Comment: Just console log the response object and share the output.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the function inside `onResolve={ }` takes two parameters: provider and data.